# How to access this object property

Tags: php, object, properties

I am trying to access an ID from this object but I am not sure how to do that. When I do a var_dump on the object I don't get anything that I can access.

```
            echo "</pre>";
            echo var_dump($usersVehiclesObject);
            echo "</pre>";
```

That ouputs:

```
string(1) "2"
```

2 is in fact the value that I am looking for, but I am not sure how to extract that from the object.

I have tried a few things at random to get it but those did not work:

```
            echo "</pre>";
            echo $usersVehiclesObject->string(1);
            echo "</pre>";

            echo "</pre>";
            echo $usersVehiclesObject->1;
            echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: That is not an object, but a string as stated.

Comment: It's a string. just do `echo $usersVehiclesObject;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not an object, its just a string..

Just echo it... :)

```
 echo $usersVehiclesObject;
```

Thats it!

ie...

```
echo "The ID is :". $usersVehicleObject;
```